# How do I form-fit my form to the handheld device?

Tags: winforms, compact-framework, windows-ce

I added a new form to my Windows CE/CF/C# app, but the form is too large -- I have to drag it around to see all of it - I thought the CF automatically made forms scale to the size of the device?

Is there a property or properties I need to set, or a particular size I need to give the form so that it will take up the entire screen but no more than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Forms are not auto-sized for WinCE (WinMo they are).  You can set it's size manually, or Maximize it to get the effect you're after.